# Firebase - permission denied after change of developer

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is an odd one! I had a couple of developers building a mobile app using Firebase and React Native. They had everything working fine and left the company at the end of January. I have since picked this up to get it in to the hands of our staff. However I am running in to issues!
Before the guys left they added me to the Firebase account, I then created an iOS application in there and have made sure that I have changed the React Native code to point to the new Firebase iOS app.
That seems to be fine as users can log in with Facebook, their credentials are added to the Authentication table and they are given a UID. That UID is then used in our database as a primary key and appears to be added just fine, however at the next read/write attempt we get a permission denied error:

`Error onDBEvent: Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission Denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission Denied}`

As this is code that I have not written I'm stabbing in the dark a bit as to where the issue may be, I think it is in this function:

```
export function likeDestination (destinationKey, score, taggedImageSetIndex, imageTagIndex) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    const user = getState().auth.auth
    let iTagIndex = imageTagIndex + 1
    let updateValue = {}

    updateValue[destinationKey] = score

    console.log('likeDestination:: userID=', user.uid);
    console.log('likeDestination:: taggedImageSetIndex=', taggedImageSetIndex);

    // Set the user's preference for this tag then update (increment) the imageTagIndex
    return firestack.database.ref(`user-data/${user.uid}/tagSets/${taggedImageSetIndex}/userScores`)
    .update(updateValue)
    .then(() => {
      return firestack.database.ref(`user-data/${user.uid}/tagSets/${taggedImageSetIndex}`).update({imageTagIndex: iTagIndex})
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error in setting destination "like" data to Firebase:', err)
      RouterActions.ErrorPage({ error: err })
    })
  }
}
```

It's worth stating that the `console.log` statements above return the correct values.
The only reference I can find for the getState function is below, not sure what the `.auth.auth` calls will do in order to get the user from the database but it seems to work!

```
export function getState (toggle) {
  return {
    type: GET_STATE,
    payload: toggle
  }
}
```

I've had a look through various posts around similar problems and they all seem to point to the rules in Firebase. The rules haven't changed since it worked and if I run those queries through the simulator I get a big tick next to the relevant read and write rule. Here are the rules for the DB:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "destination-scores": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    },
    "destinations": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    },
    "tv-admins": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": false
    },
    "tv-queues": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "tv-screens": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "root.child('tv-admins').child('ids').val().contains(auth.uid)",
      ".indexOn": "status"
    },
    "user-data": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The queries in the code sample above are targeting the `user-data` rules and in the simulator that works fine, just not from the app. As I mentioned, the rules have not changed. What has changed is that the code is now running on my machine, as opposed to the original developer's, and there is a new iOS app created in Firebase.
As I also mentioned, I have ensured that I have replaced the old Firebase API key, messaging sender ID, Auth domain, DB URL and storage bucket with the new details. I believe this is working as users can log in via Facebook and get to the first stage in the app... at which point their user data has been added to the `user-data` table.
I'm new to Firebase and React Native so I'm not entirely sure where, in the code, this is happening but I suspect it may be this function:

```
export function connectUserData (firedb, user, authProvider, onUserDataChanged) {
  const now = new Date()

  return firedb.ref(`user-data/${user.uid}`)
  .update({ email: user.email, connectedAt: now.toISOString(), authProvider: authProvider })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error in updating meta data in connectUserData():', err)
    throw new Error('Error in updating meta data in connectUserData()!')
  })
}
```

This is called as part of an init function that checks if a user is authenticated... as in, they exist in the Authentication table/list in Firebase

I simply do not understand why I'm getting permission denied when I had permission, literally, seconds before! Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: you can connect to the `user-data` only if a user is authenticated and only the user's data

Comment: @OussemaAroua thanks for your comment... that is where the problem lies. I am connected as an authenticated user and only trying to edit that authenticated user's data but it is giving me a permissions denied message